# Is heat treatment the only means known to man for increasing grain size in steel?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, crystals, metals, ferromagnetism

It is well known that steel grains tend to grow larger under heat treatment. Is it possible to enlarge grain size through any other means?

I cannot seem to find anything via web search. If steel is too narrow a scope, the question can be generalized to all metals.

Comment: Do you consider melting and resolidifying to be a heat treatment?

Comment: Yes. I am thinking more along the lines of a chemical treatment, or the application of electromagnetic fields / ultrasonic waves (all of which I have searched to no avail)

Comment: Heat is important because it gives atoms more energy, making bonds break and reform more frequently. This increases the rate at which grains can grow. So an alternative to heat treatment might be to wait a really long time. You might wait the age of the universe.

Comment: [Stress-induced grain growth](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11661-014-2258-5), [strain-induced grain growth](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.75.045414?casa_token=Mcfxmve4GtEAAAAA%3AekSgULWUx2fLXo4hYsZOvXnSQnnneBIr8PUJVNLGrfmlYf5dEqGyNCN1ntkwGRLdj17jy7x5ZPzyHw), [electric-field-induced grain growth](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0955221918305272?casa_token=WMW34PFAaWAAAAAA:d54iY99gff67cvCYP_BGgywR-QgGIT-ZdYfHUUcslDqpS7I88RrtKvzfG8AisxKqo7w2DG9HCA), for example, offer entry points for investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't and here is why.

Grain growth is caused by thermally-activated diffusion of metal atoms in the solid state. The diffusion rate depends on the temperature of the solid metal through a mechanism referred to sometimes as *rate kinetics*. High temperature adds agitation to the atoms in the metallic lattice and makes them jump positions in the lattice more frequently, and conversely for lower temperatures.

This picture holds for almost all common "engineering" metals- iron, aluminum, copper, etc. Those materials possess no *athermal grain growth mechanisms*.